# Validations with the SQLAlchemy version of Python Eve

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, eve

I'd like to use the Eve framework for creating a REST api and performing data validations. But I want to use the SQLAlchemy version of Eve with an rdbms back end. The Eve-SQLAlchemy documentation says nothing about how to do this.

For example, I will have a db table called `People`:

```
# sql_schema.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property, relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    firstname = Column(String(80))
    lastname = Column(String(120))
    fullname = column_property(firstname + " " + lastname)
```

Later I tell Eve about my database definitions:

```
from eve_sqlalchemy.config import DomainConfig, ResourceConfig
from sql_schema import People

# The default schema is generated using DomainConfig:
DOMAIN = DomainConfig({
    'people': ResourceConfig(People)
}).render()

# now I can stuff in my validations, a bit klunkily
DOMAIN['people']['schema']['firstname'].update({'allowed': ['Pete']})
```

The above works! If I try to store `People` with a firstname other than 'Pete' I get a validation error. But it's a bit klunky to bolt on the validations after the schema definition like this. For instance, Eve picks up the max length 80 constraint from the `People` table definition. It would be nice if the `firstname` allowed constraint could be specified there too. Is there a recommended approach, and is it supported at all or liable to break in a future version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to clarify the relationship between `DomainConfig` and Eve settings in the docs: https://eve-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#eve-settings :

> You can do so using `DomainConfig` and `ResourceConfig`, which
>   will give you a default schema (`DOMAIN` dictionary) derived from your
>   SQLAlchemy models. This is intended as a starting point and to save you
>   from redundant configuration, but there's nothing wrong with customizing this
>   dictionary if you need to!

```
# examples/simple/settings.py

# ...

# Even adding custom validations just for the REST-layer is possible:
DOMAIN['invoices']['schema']['number'].update({
    'min': 10000
})
```

That said, if you actually have a constraint specified in your SQLAlchemy models that is not automatically translated into proper validation rules in Eve's schema definition, please open an issue!